# Letting team present Strategy to CEO

Tags: manager, leadership, teamleader

Is it a wise decision as head of adepartment to let your direct reports present their strategy to the CEO, or would that hurt how you are seen as a leader?

Comment: Depends so much on your CEO, your team, the size of your company and so many other things. This is the sort of decision you're hired to make, so make it.

Comment: Needs more detail about the company and type of CEO.  An open CEO in a startup absolutely fine; a Fortune 500 CEO who fires people for wasting an hour of her time absolutely not.

Answer (score 2):

*"Is it a wise decision as head of adepartment to let your direct reports present their strategy to the CEO, or would that hurt how you are seen as a leader?"*

Obviously depending strongly on your relationship with the boss, company-culture and workflow, one option would be to present the strategy as a team including you.

If your boss has time and is keen on having a presentation, you could shedule a meeting where you first present the general concept of the proposed strategy, talk about advantages, and so on - Basically a general introduction and short summary.

Then let your direct reports/team-members talk about their individual parts in making this strategy happen.

This way you keep the leader-role and also let your direct reports have a part in the whole presentation. But again, this really depends on how much your CEO wants to get involved in decisions which are normally your responsibilty.